# How do I give a root directory to all requests?

Tags: 9, proxies

A project I'm working on has a slightly unusual requirement. We have Drupal 9 running inside of Apache and Drupal is currently the only application running on the hostname. Our Drupal 9 installation is installed with composer drupal/recommended-project -- meaning that index.php is located inside of /var/www/html/web/

Everything works as it should, https://example.com/ give the front page and https://example.com/node/1 gives the node with nid of 1.

A portal application that is serving as a public internet proxy for our application wants us to prefix **ALL** requests with a root context directory. So instead of https://example.com/ we are being asked to use https://example.com/app_name/ and https://example.com/app_name/node/1. Static assets should also be handled with the same root context directory in the front of the path.

I'd like to try and stick to Apache configurations instead of mucking around with the Drupal file directory structure.

Some things I've tried:

1. Custom implementations of InboundPathProcessorInterface and OutboundPathProcessorInterface
2. Setting the Apache DocumentRoot configuration to point to /var/www/html instead of /var/www/html/web

For (1): this was obviously overly complicated and doesn't solve the static asset requirements.

For (2): This would require renaming the 'web' directory to 'app_name' and would require additional Apache access restrictions to make sure the true root directory is not accessible -- I don't want any files or directories inside of /var/www/html/ to be accessible. For example, files inside of /var/www/html/vendor/ can be accessed. I know this can be blocked with an .htaccess file, but I'm trying to avoid altering the standard Drupal installation as much as possible. This change might also affect drush or my IDE in odd ways.

Is there any way of configuring Apache to "trick" the browser into using a root directory that doesn't actually exist?

Comment: Just move your project directory up one level, so that /web is a sibling to your webroot. Then either change `/web` to your webroot in composer.json, or do a simlink from your webroot to `/web`

Comment: @jaypan Interesting, but definitely altering the standard Drupal file structure (of drupal/recommended-project). I might still give it a try.

Comment: It doesn't alter it. This is how it was designed.